# Script for combining changes in key value pairs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to combine 2 files which contains key value pairs for string localizations.
I should keep added values from file 1, and rewrite updated values from file 2.

File 1:

```
"cart.title" = "Cart";
"cart.subtitle" = "Price";

"checkout.title" = "Checkout";
```

File 2:

```
"cart.title" = "Cart";

"checkout.title" = "Super checkout";
```

Desired result:

```
"cart.title" = "Cart";
"cart.subtitle" = "Price";

"checkout.title" = "Super checkout";
```

I have tried it with awk, but problem is that it always moves new strings from file 1 to end of file. And I want to keep my strings grouped as original file.

```
awk -F= '!a[$1]++' 2.strings 1.strings > results.strings
```

But I am struggling to maintain original order and result looks like this:

```
"cart.title" = "Cart";

"checkout.title" = "Super Checkout";
"cart.subtitle" = "Price";
```

I think that it should be pretty easy task for anyone who's domain is Linux.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please do confirm why `"checkout.title" = "Checkout";` line is not present in output.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Because it was replaced by `"checkout.title" = "Super Checkout";` from file 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$1]=$0
  arr2[++count]=$1
  next
}
($1 in arr1){
  arr1[$1]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print arr1[arr2[i]]
  }
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  arr1[$1]=$0               ##Creating arr1 with index of $1 and value of $0.
  arr2[++count]=$1          ##Creating arr2 with index of ++count and value of $0.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr1){               ##Checking condition if $1 is in arr1 then do following.
  arr1[$1]=$0               ##Setting arr1 value to $0 with index of $1.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){    ##Starting a for loop from 1 to till value of count.
    print arr1[arr2[i]]     ##Printing value of arr1 with index of arr2 here.
  }
}
' file1 file2               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { map[$1]=$0; next }
    { print ($1 in map ? map[$1] : $0) }
' file2 file1
"cart.title" = "Cart";
"cart.subtitle" = "Price";

"checkout.title" = "Super checkout";
```